# Class 'DOTNET' not found with PHP 5.4.7

Tags: php, asp.net

i Get this Error `Class 'DOTNET' not found` with PHP 5.4.7 when i tried to use PHP DOTNET class...

and i googled and found some help saying edit php.ini file and add the following line

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

but still the issue not fixed. . .

Any help pls

Comment: Commenting or un commenting the line wont help you until unless you have that specified `dll` at appropriate location

Comment: i tried it like this way

extension= E:\xampp\php\ext\php_com_dotnet.dll

still fatal error :(

Comment: Is it the correct path??

Comment: Yes it is correct path..

do i have to add anymore lines like

Enable DOTNET enable COM like that...

Comment: make it -> extension=php_com_dotnet.dll  and let me know then

Comment: no its still Fatal Error.. are you on PHP 5.4.7 or greater than that.. can you try this sample code and tell whats the result..
http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php

Comment: I tried and its working fine at my end - o/p - Hello .Net

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the .Net runtime on your web server and check whether it is enabled or notby following thescreenshot -

[image: extension]

If not enabled, enable it in `php.ini` if `dll` exists -

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

Once done `RESTART` the server.

Comment: well im on Xampp 1.8.1 - PHP version 5.4.7.. nd read on php.net that they have removed dotnet and com support in latest releases.. but they said we can manuallly add.. but no luck